# Detecting balls on a pool table

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm currently working on a project where I need to be able to very reliable get the positions of the balls on a pool table.

I'm using a Kinect v2 above the table as the source.

Initial [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFpR2.png) looks like this (after converting it to 8-bit from 16-bit by throwing away pixels which is not around table level):

[image: pool table top view kinect depth raw]

Then a I subtract a reference image with the empty table from the current image.

After thresholding and equalization it looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNeAg.png)

[image: pool table top view kinect depth processed]

It's fairly easy to detect the individual balls on a single image, the problem is that I have to do it constantly with 30fps.

Difficulties:

- Low resolution image (512*424), a ball is around 4-5 pixel in diameter
- Kinect depth image has a lot of noise from this distance (2 meters)
- Balls look different on the depth image, for example the black ball is kind of inverted compared to the others
- If they touch each other then they can become one blob on the image, if I try to separate them with depth thresholding (only using the top of the balls) then some of the balls can disappear from the image
- It's really important that anything other than balls should not be detected e.g.: cue, hands etc...

My process which kind of works but not reliable enough:

- 16bit to 8bit by thresholding
- Subtracting sample image with empty table
- Cropping
- Thresholding
- Equalizing
- Eroding
- Dilating
- Binary threshold
- Contour finder
- Some further algorithms on the output coordinates

The problem is that a pool cue or hand can be detected as a ball and also if two ball touches then it can cause issues. Also tried with hough circles but with even less success. (Works nicely if the Kinect is closer but then it cant cover the whole table)

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would start with making the IRL setup as easy as possible for tracking: doing as much as possible on the physical setup and as little as possible with image processing. If the active area is scaled by 117% percent the pockets are still visible, therefore the sensor can be moved closer. Additionally, from the depth image above it looks like the sensor is at an angle (from the perspective skew and diagonal left to right gradient of the pool table). Try aligning the sensor perfectly perpendicular to the surface and sturdily mounting the sensor...

Comment: ...it sounds like the closer the sensor is the to the the table, the easier it will be to see, but you might easily reach a point where the balls are visible, but the whole table is out of the kinects view frustum (more kinects may be required to cover the whole table area at a decent height). There are a couple of questions that come to mind: 1. do the balls need to tracked during gameplay in realtime (when they might move very fast and cause a motion blur on a cam?), 2. do the balls need to be identified ? 3. do the players need to be segmented as well ?

Comment: You can try hough circles detection. First compute edges and detect hough circles

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeProfenza. Moving closer and aligning better helped a lot and also i moved to blob detection instead of edge detection which works much better. Unfortunately using more sensors is not an option. 1. Yes, I have to track them during game play. 2. I don't have to identify them but i have to keep a their "id's" constant trough the frames. 3. Player segmentation is not required.

Comment: Now that the tracking works pretty well (I would say around 90%-95%) the main problem left is that I have to know if a ball is the same as it was on the last frame, which I'm kind of getting it right slowly but if you have some clues on that topic to it would be great. Now I'm calculating the distances between frames and also factoring in the velocity of the balls. Maybe there is a better method which I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding comments above:

I recommend improving the IRL setup as much as possible.
Most of the time it's easier to ensure a reliable setup than to try to "fix" that user computer vision before even getting to detecting/tracking anything.

My suggestions are:

1. Move the camera closer to the table. (the image you posted can be 117% bigger and still cover the pockets)
2. Align the camera to be perfectly perpendicular to the table (and ensure the sensor stand is sturdy and well fixed): it will be easier to process a perfect top down view than a slightly tilted view (which is what the depth gradient shows). (sure the data can be rotated, but why waste CPU cycles when you can simply keep the sensor straight)

With a more reliable setup you should be able to threshold based on depth.
You can possible threshold to the centre of balls since the information bellow is occluded anyway. The balls do not deform, so it the radius decreases fast the ball probably went in a pocket.

One you have a clear threshold image, you can `findContours()` and [minEnclosingCircle()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle). Additionally you should contrain the result based on min and max radius values to avoid other objects that may be in the view (hands, pool cues, etc.). Also have a look at [moments()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments) and be sure to read [Adrian's excellent Ball Tracking with OpenCV article](http://Ball%20Tracking%20with%20OpenCV)

[image: pyimagesearch.com Ball Tracking with OpenCV article preview]

It's using Python, but you should be able to find OpenCV equivalent call for the language you use.

**In terms tracking**
If you use OpenCV 2.4 you should look into [OpenCV 2.4's tracking algorithms](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) (such as Lucas-Kanade).
If you already use OpenCV 3.0, it has it's own [list of contributed tracking algorithms](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html) (such as TLD).

I recommend starting with Moments first: use the simplest and least computationally expensive setup initially and see how robuts the results are before going into the more complex algorithms (which will take to understand and get the parameters right to get expected results out of)

Comment: Glad it helps. The only other thing I would be careful with is fast motion that may result in motion blur. Hopefully that won't be case. Sounds like a fun project. It would be awesome if you could share the outcomes later on. Best of luck